# fgetc skips first character in file

Tags: c, fgetc

In the while loop, the fgetc command is skipping the first character, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
void generate_people(FILE *p, struct person *a){
    int c;

    while((c = getc(p)) != EOF){
        fscanf(p, "%s %[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ], 
          %[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ] %d, %d %s.", 
            a->fornavn, a->efternavn, a->vejnavn, 
            &a->vejnummer, &a->postnummer, a->bynavn);
        a++; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon. 
 More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not shown your input data or the actual or expected output.  However, you call `fgetc()` in the loop, which reads the first character into `c`, and then you use `fscanf()`.  Now, the `fscanf()` won't ever see the character read into `c`.  Also note that the scan sets support range notation such as `%[a-zA-Z ]` which makes your format string more comprehensible.  Most likely, you should use `while (fscanf(p, "…", …) == 6)` and ignore `fgetc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first character is in `c`. Use the result of `fscanf()` instead of `(c = getc(p)) != EOF` to detect error or `EOF`:

```
void generate_people(FILE *p, struct person *a)
{
    while (fscanf(p, "%s %[a-zA-Z], %[a-zA-Z] %d, %d %s.",
                     a->fornavn, a->efternavn, a->vejnavn, 
                     &a->vejnummer, &a->postnummer, a->bynavn) == 6)
    {
        ++a; 
    }    
}
```

#### Full example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    char fornavn[30];
    char efternavn[30];
    char vejnavn[30];
    int  vejnummer;
    int  postnummer;
    char bynavn[30];
};

struct person* generate_people(FILE *p, struct person *a)
{
    while (fscanf(p, "%29s %29[a-zA-Z], %29[a-zA-Z] %d, %d %29s",  // ****)
           a->fornavn, a->efternavn, a->vejnavn,
           &a->vejnummer, &a->postnummer, a->bynavn) == 6)
    {
        ++a;
    }
    return a;
}

void person_print(struct person *a)
{
    printf("\"%s\" \"%s\", \"%s\" %d, %d \"%s\"\n",
           a->fornavn, a->efternavn, a->vejnavn,
           a->vejnummer, a->postnummer, a->bynavn);
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct person people[10];
    struct person *end = generate_people(input, people);

    for (struct person *i = people; i != end; ++i)
        person_print(i);

    fclose(input);
}
```

#### Input file:

```
Lars Jensen, Engtoften 23, 7182 Bredsten
Bo Olsen, Vestergade 56, 4261 Dalmose
Kurt Jensen, Haderslevvej 15, 8370 Hadsten
Birte Madsen, Universitetsvej 899, 9000 Aalborg
Kaj Moberg, Halevindingevej 2, 2670 Greve
Bo Rise, Hadsund Landvej 56, 8900 Randers
```

#### Output:

```
"Lars" "Jensen", "Engtoften" 23, 7182 "Bredsten"
"Lars" "Jensen", "Engtoften" 23, 7182 "Bredsten"
"Bo" "Olsen", "Vestergade" 56, 4261 "Dalmose"
"Kurt" "Jensen", "Haderslevvej" 15, 8370 "Hadsten"
"Birte" "Madsen", "Universitetsvej" 899, 9000 "Aalborg"
"Kaj" "Moberg", "Halevindingevej" 2, 2670 "Greve"
```

****) Please not that you should **NEVER** use `"%s"` with `*scanf()` without specifying a width for the field to read: `"%NNNs"` where `NNN` is the number of characters. For an array of size 30: `"%29"` ... 29 + 1 for the terminating 0.

Comment: @LasseHarde Are you taking that course: http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/impr-c/ ?